# Styles not showing up with bundles up Chakra UI Components using Rollup (with typescript React and Chakra UI)

Tags: reactjs, typescript, storybook, chakra-ui

I am trying to build a Chakra UI Component Library using Typescript, React and Chakra UI. However after bundling the folder and using npm link to test my library out, none of the CSS styling is showing up, the theme works but other than that everything related to the styling is stripped off.

My rollup config is as follows

```
import resolve from "@rollup/plugin-node-resolve";
import commonjs from "@rollup/plugin-commonjs";
import typescript from "@rollup/plugin-typescript";
import terser from "@rollup/plugin-terser";
import external from "rollup-plugin-peer-deps-external";
import dts from "rollup-plugin-dts";
import svgr from "@svgr/rollup";
import packageJson from "./package.json" assert { type: "json" };

export default [
  {
    input: "src/index.ts",
    output: [
      {
        file: packageJson.main,
        format: "cjs",
        sourcemap: true,
        name: "react-lib",
      },
      {
        file: packageJson.module,
        format: "esm",
        sourcemap: true,
      },
    ],
    external: Object.keys(packageJson.peerDependencies),
    plugins: [
      external(),
      resolve(),
      commonjs(),
      typescript({ tsconfig: "./tsconfig.json" }),
      terser(),
      svgr(),
    ],
  },
  {
    input: "dist/esm/types/index.d.ts",
    output: [{ file: "dist/index.d.ts", format: "esm" }],
    external: [/\.css$/],
    plugins: [dts()],
  },
];
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "name-of-file",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "description": "Vivly's Internal Component Library",
  "main": "dist/cjs/index.js",
  "module": "dist/esm/index.js",
  "types": "dist/index.d.ts",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "build": "rollup -c",
    "storybook": "storybook dev -p 6006",
    "build-storybook": "storybook build"
  },
  "author": "uhuh",
  "license": "ISC",
  "peerDependencies": {
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "@chakra-ui/react": "^2.5.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.21.0",
    "@chakra-ui/icons": "^2.0.17",
    "@chakra-ui/react": "^2.5.1",
    "@chakra-ui/storybook-addon": "^4.0.16",
    "@emotion/react": "^11.10.6",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.10.6",
    "@rollup/plugin-commonjs": "^24.0.1",
    "@rollup/plugin-node-resolve": "^15.0.1",
    "@rollup/plugin-terser": "^0.4.0",
    "@rollup/plugin-typescript": "^11.0.0",
    "@storybook/addon-actions": "^7.0.0-beta.59",
    "@storybook/addon-essentials": "^7.0.0-beta.59",
    "@storybook/addon-interactions": "^7.0.0-beta.59",
    "@storybook/addon-links": "^7.0.0-beta.59",
    "@storybook/addon-mdx-gfm": "^7.0.0-beta.59",
    "@storybook/react": "^7.0.0-beta.59",
    "@storybook/react-webpack5": "^7.0.0-beta.59",
    "@storybook/testing-library": "^0.0.14-next.1",
    "@svgr/rollup": "^6.5.1",
    "@types/react": "^18.0.28",
    "@types/rollup-plugin-peer-deps-external": "^2.2.1",
    "babel-loader": "^8.3.0",
    "framer-motion": "^10.0.1",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "recharts": "^2.4.3",
    "rollup": "^3.17.3",
    "rollup-plugin-dts": "^5.2.0",
    "rollup-plugin-peer-deps-external": "^2.2.4",
    "storybook": "^7.0.0-beta.59",
    "typescript": "^4.9.5"
  }
}
```

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "esnext",
    "jsx": "react",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "dist",
    "strict": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true
  }
}
```

I might as well add that I don't have any css files in the components folder as all the styling I have done has been through themes and component styling of Chakra UI Component props.

I tried looking into solutions or guides as to how to make a component library using Chakra , but I couldn't find any. I find

Comment: I’m experiencing the same thing and looking for a solution as well.

Answer (score 0):

I am also experiencing the same issue. To have styles working on the imported components from your external library, you have to wrap your main project in a `ChakraProvider` exported from your external library.

Is `@chakra-ui/react` included as a dependency in both your main project and external library?

If you import `ChakraProvider` directly from `@chakra-ui/react` in your main project, components from your external library won't be styled. In this case however, components imported directly from `@chakra-ui/react` would be properly styled. Unfortunately, your styles will only apply to components in your main project or components from your external library.

The only way that I've been able to resolve this issue and have all components from `@chakra-ui/react` and my external library is to re-export everything I need from `@chakra-ui/react` in the external library. Then I would just import anything from Chakra from my library instead.

I don't know if this is a *good* solution. Would love to hear from others.

Also some questions:

- Does your resulting bundle create all the necessary `d.ts` files?
- Are you exporting your theme with associated component styles?

Comment: Hi there, sorry for the late reply. Unfortunately due to the numerous build problems posed by chakra we switched to tailwind with shadcn to build our component library. Thank you for taking time out to answer the questions , I will be sure to try out the solution when I get the chance to revisit the old component library. To answer your questions - we were exporting the theme and d.ts files, but the point you raised does make sense, as that was the behaviour we encountered.